# If $X$ is arc-connected and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function, then $f(X)$ is also arc-connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**If $X$ is arc-connected and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function, then $f(X)$ is also arc-connected**

Is this statement true? If it is true, I have the following proof and I do not know if it's okay, in case it's not right, could you tell me where I'm wrong? Is there any counterexample to this? Thank you.

Take $x,y\in f(X)$ then there exist $z,w\in X$ such that $f(z)=x, f(w)=y$, as $X$ is arc-connected then there exists a continuous function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ such that $g(0)=z, g(1)=w$, then $f(g(0))=f(z)=x$ and $f(g(1))=f(w)=y$ and $fg:[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Comment: it is a good proof

Comment: Does arc-connected mean path connected?

Comment: @zhw. yes......

Comment: What is it about your proof that you are concerned with?

Comment: @copper.hat 
Is that a task where I have to say if the statements are true, if they are true I have to give a test or if they are false I have to give a counterexample.

Comment: @Nash: That's not what I am asking. Why are you not confident of your proof? What step bothers you?

Comment: @copper.hat 
the power to compose functions that way

Comment: Arc connected is not the same as path connected.  Your proposition is false  unless f is injective.  What is true is that continuous functions preserve path connectedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true and your proof is correct, the composition of continuous functions is continuous, so if $g:[0,1] \to X$ is continuous so is $f \circ g : [0,1] \to X$ and (repeating your argument) $(f \circ g)(0) = f(g(0)) = f(z) = x$ and $(f \circ g)(1)  =f(g(1)) = f(w) = y$ so it is by definition a path from $x$ to $y$ (both in $f[X]$). So $f[X]$ is indeed path-connected.

As an exercise now show that any product $\prod_i X_i$ of path-connected spaces is also path-connected.

Comment: Exercise.   Show arc connected is preserved by continuous injections.